# Assistance with switch variables

Tags: javascript

The variable room_x_beds are necessary, I am not bothered about the default area.

I can not assign the value of var room_x_beds to var x ?

I do not understand why.

**Code:**

```
var room_1_beds = 2;
var room_2_beds = 2;
var room_3_beds = 1;
var give_num = prompt();
var x;

switch(give_num){
    case "1":
        x = room_1_beds;
        break;
    case "2":
        x = room_2_beds;
        break;
    case "3":
        x = room_3_beds;
        break;
    default:
    break;
        }

switch(x){
    case "1":
        console.log ("text");
    break;
    case "2":
        console.log ("text");
    break;
    default:
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values of the second `switch` statement should be numbers not strings.

```js
var room_1_beds = 2;
var room_2_beds = 2;
var room_3_beds = 1;
var give_num = prompt();
var x;
switch(give_num){
    case "1":
        x = room_1_beds;
        break;
    case "2":
        x = room_2_beds;
        break;
    case "3":
        x = room_3_beds;
        break;
    default:
    break;
        }

switch(x){
    case 1:
        console.log ("text");
    break;
    case 2:
        console.log ("text");
    break;
    default:
    break;
}
```

Comment: you could add the strict compairing as well.

Comment: @NinaScholz I made a bit search about this and I found that *A switch statement first evaluates its expression. It then looks for the first case clause whose expression evaluates to the same value as the result of the input expression (using strict comparison, ===) and transfers control to that clause, executing the associated statements.* at MDN, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch. Isn't this that you are referring to. If this is, then this is the default behaviour. Thanks in advance.

Comment: right, that is the reason to change the type. both parts are checked with strict comparison, like `===`.

Comment: @NinaScholz So what is missing?

Comment: i think you could mention, that the comparison is strict, not abstract, like the op has (maybe) thought.